# Connecting double balanced TRS outputs to TRS unbalanced input

Tags: cable

I'm looking into buying an audio interface, and have an eye on Native Instruments Audio 2.

https://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/komplete/audio-interfaces/komplete-audio-1-audio-2/

This device has two balanced 6.3mm TRS outputs (left and right). I currently don't own any advanced monitors, so initially I'd like to use my computer speakers which have a single 3.5mm TRS plug (stereo).

Looking through my box of adapters and cables, I see I have stuff to physically connect these two if I use 6.3mm TS (not TRS) plugs to connect to the interface. But I'm concerned that this still will not work, since the outputs of the interface are actually balanced TRS.

Looking at the connecting guide that Native Instruments have, the illustration actually depicts plugging in TS plugs, but maybe that's just a mistakes they've made?

https://www.native-instruments.com/en/komplete-audio-2-quickstart/connecting-devices/

Can I connect using adapters only, or is other equipment necessary?

Any help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unbalanced cables and equipment will connect fine with balanced outputs. You will just not get the advantage of balanced output: you only get one channel of the two-channels sent down the cable.

Balanced cables send the same signal out on both channels (its like a stereo output), but one signal is intentionally inverted. The receiving equipment then inverts that one side of the inverted signal and adds it to the other signal. When you do this on a waveform, it is additive: it reinforces the signal, but since the unavoidable noise from the transmission hardware and cabling is now flipped, it is summing the "positive" value of the noise and a "negative" value of the same noise, which sums to zero. So you get noise cancellation and you get a bigger difference between any noise still there and the intended signal which was also summed.

Comment: "*...but one signal is intentionally inverted...*" Actually they don't usually do that, because then you have a 50% drop in level when you use this unbalanced.  What they do instead is drive the ring with a regular active circuit the same as the tip but outputting 0V.  For balanced use you can still invert the ring signal and add it to the tip, removing noise, but the signal level is unchanged.  And for unbalanced use the signal level between T and S again is what it is.  Note that actively outputting 0V is not the same as just connecting it to ground, because what matters is output impedance.